# How to resolve Import Error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I did this :

```
 import calender
```

But gives me this error :

```
 ImportError: No module named calender
```

What should I do?

Comment: You've misspelled calendar

Comment: This is off topic as it is a simple typographical error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo in the name, it's `calendar`, not `calender`:

```
import calendar
```